# PowerShell regular expression to delete folders that were extracted windows patches to root of C drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Need a PowerShell regular expression pattern to delete left behind folders that were extracted by windows patches from root of C drive

```
c:\0260cbbd38dbbbea2543f8
c:\096ea4b36d877b65dc6c
c:\0cf52cad06ab7b5cfe2b4042c8
c:\0d90c7a3bdd67a5212aa527bc49b
c:\0e2180b528a8c152566816291c2252
c:\1050411ef7c0228177
c:\120dc98c3c427148e0e847
c:\1266b191a6041be04da921
c:\134f4bae5dcd171cba9d795c
c:\163037d9459286ec00226ecba86c6b
c:\19c5e16d96cff11fb276
c:\1a45ab7c977d005fa74016
c:\1ce14958a6b03c4fbdd0aa7595
c:\1d4dd4b97f3bc25610224b794970
c:\1e8dca560de070e9c7ce5ea666b1a2
c:\225f0c8c83d4680dcaf7f3
c:\27d0be422124c8e6895f55a2d92e6b45
c:\27e73ccf209a2d26b918bae979003e62
c:\2cbfba046b23288dda36b27681
c:\2d19c1e6f0c6d79a27f11258ed5a
c:\3368da3dec9eaf0c1bd2aa3e
c:\3572040545b171d83e9a8edbc517
c:\3651fe9fb1a4d98c8752b834c823fb
c:\37bc2d84450d0712ba434ab58b9be3b5
c:\397ede84503ab8705c61
c:\39b805b4909ca6ab7444
c:\3c3c48d33d8849a8738b547e9a
c:\3c4b849f11f1f97e739d91f23f
c:\406699ef4baa3836e6
c:\430dca3d98c1433dbb06c41b
c:\438f43589bf4d2e91de92257
c:\442b9d9e1f12d6527a355fbb94
c:\444fc210df5624fc57ed431b41
c:\4e80466bc0bd9a225a1d0c6c49eda3
c:\513f6e8fd2ec94ee80e1
c:\527c723b1c15e5ad1777f0
c:\52c8c81ce00ef83612bea8
c:\52cf084fe6416eac75251f
c:\53bcd710184608538ed626f9
c:\5555c66e2524b093ccde17168dc2
c:\576e7da4ab59dff0a4fc453bd09ce380
c:\58af12fd0051615253
c:\595108cb19dd9e45343e
c:\5c0519db74ebb86fa611ca76a2
c:\5c18f69a206888d586d0d6bfe1
c:\5dad9ce7201f38aca9fd6fbc63f3
c:\64cf5b2b98e7bfd45bf258b06e
c:\66a725a452271ff883431f2dd7b0f1
c:\68b4cee980651b3fbc
c:\718c43ef809499044a3c
c:\734073c2f7eda3b4c38a19e0
c:\737a421b02032d614a7a1c45
c:\74edd213e1fe718df94032a51d
c:\781f57f5ac41af00be
c:\7af4485cc5429456445957
c:\7d2d566780048cba452b03c6b263
c:\7fe3e7297a62e48255533539033ee50c
c:\8228bc4c03fd5b2f1ebb24
c:\83ad2f96485c40340a2cd782
c:\88a6f42b17c78a0638
c:\88fd60c16b19a0cf73
c:\8a588e86a91e3ca897f542
c:\8acdfcd173abff9029beb5
c:\8b9e7e1b322c408d340970f0
c:\8ff8bb90108d7627eb1267d09ba0fb55
c:\90b7703a90a2c24c7b
c:\93d276f9dc924a406a6ed01b
c:\9c7ef323ec48ed5587661b4693
c:\a1eb22f89d6a07c904db
c:\a47813cc369c82be7143f47185
c:\a49ce62ce9ce98096931d23c51
c:\a61924dfd4704703d5e39c5281d29e
c:\a63849d1d3bbd85790ee4a01299bd6
c:\a753ff49744ccadded681251d331d35f
c:\ad975367f3e001f51a14c9908b23
c:\b0face991a3ad869ca
c:\b82598682fc78f9305
c:\ba8a744c5b959384186bc4
c:\babdd0ba0a07d3c9223cef
c:\bc0b82ac0babb98b8342350bc8
c:\bdc2d2f2f3bc01003a91fe0e1459
c:\c0fae0409a0b10ea75
c:\c1180e96da82fae50747
c:\c4f0fd540da02906b56741b3c9
c:\ca7f59e621d33ce834ba0d
c:\cd19f0d28269630b2a63986edd91
c:\d486081e034c03d07b7fdc7d25
c:\d4f6b9fd6bf99442f9ccf0dae3
c:\d557a9f6fa2474f0d1622c381b03
c:\d571c66922d2adca2707b43c4d91
c:\d628ab789f80774608696b5ab49702
c:\d78bc5349052849aaca6eea917eb6f97
c:\db7cbb79e4cec11e0750e59c
c:\db7d5b6b5ea0efe9b7bcf9cf
c:\de2be517ad36995b3045c5288bd68f
c:\e0a72cd7cc448809cb
c:\e196772ec200ace6dcbd
c:\ea3a0fea3bdf080ee65b60
c:\ec1b70f46f6fe0088a451a1662
c:\f04ab325c03a1380ca
c:\f3f4d3bf0fb6fdc477c13c99
c:\f43507f18e2024ffdb8ad2b189
c:\f54ce6242b345e5cf3946c98f585
c:\f65be2c2b3f903d1e8b82942fd5e8f
c:\f7f6d21a696415c6b8b2869988dee5f6
c:\fbe5089abb1a64e9b560ac32
c:\ffeb5928a51b311728428591da5683e2
```

this gets me all that start with the number, but need a more solid pattern, as well as the one that starts with the letter to make sure I'm not accidently deleting other windows directories without using exclusion filter

```
gci c:\ | ? {$_.name -match '^[^a-zA-Z].*'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you closest to getting the folder names that are in the GUID format (0..9|a..f|A..F).  Since the length you have is arbitrary, this match should get you pretty close to what you are looking for. I used this with your folder names and got all those except for the extra few I created. Test it before deleting.

```
gci C:\ | ? { $_.Name -match '[0-9a-fA-F]{4}[0-9a-fA-F]{5}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a slightly different way to determine if the dir name is a hexadecimal string. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a list of dirinfo items
  you will need to get that via `Get-ChildItem` with the appropriate selectors to get only directories.
- iterates thru the list
- checks to see if the string contains ONLY hexadecimal chars
  note that i added 3 items with invalid chars - the 2nd, 4th, and 6th items.
- write out an "is/is not" message

the code ...

```
# fake reading in a list of directories
#    in real life, use Get-ChildItem -Directory
$InStuff = @(
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\0260cbbd38dbbbea2543f8'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\zzz096ea4b36d877b65dc6c'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\0cf52cad06ab7b5cfe2b4042c8'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\0d90c7a3bdd67-q-w-r-t'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\0e2180b528a8c152566816291c2252'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\1050_411ef7c0228177'
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\120dc98c3c427148e0e847'
    )

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $IsHex = $IS_Item.Name -match "[a-f0-9]{$($IS_Item.Name.Length)}"

    if ($IsHex)
        {
        Write-Host ('{0} _is_ a hexadecimal string.' -f $IS_Item)
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('    {0} is not a hexadecimal string.' -f $IS_Item)
        }
    }
```

i leave it to you to write the deletion code. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

To find **all** folders with names contaning only hexadecimal characters (only digits 0..9 and letters a..f):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Directory -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-f\d]+$' }
```

To find only those starting with a digit:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Directory -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[\d][a-f\d]+$' }
```

To find only those starting with a letter a..f:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Directory -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-f][a-f\d]+$' }
```

Hope that helps

<sup>The regex `-match` operator works case-insensitive, so no need to use `[a-fA-F]`</sup>

P.S. Since you also tagged this question with `PowerShell-2.0`, for versions below 3.0, there is no `-Directory` switch and you need to specify this in the `Where-Object` clause like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '^[a-f][a-f\d]+$' }
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. All of the answers helped to filter out matches. I added an exclusion list of the core windows directories to make sure I'm not deleting something important. I will keep my fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't an exact answer without more information or creating more conditions. You could take the approach of matching directory names based on the number of alphanumeric alternations you see.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Force -Directory | Where Name -match '([a-f]+\d+){2}'
```